# How to pass mainframe file name in enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient

Tags: java, ftp, mainframe

I am trying to download a file from ftp server using `com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient` and the file name is "ABC.DEF.GHI.JKL(0)", This is a mainframe file and it is a valid file name(checked with mainframe admin).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // extract command-line arguments
    String host = "111.111.111.111";
    String username = "bbbbbbbb";
    String password = "cccccccccp";
    String filename = "ABC.DEF.GHI.JKL(0)";

    // set up logger so that we get some output
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ConnectToServer.class);
    Logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);

    FileTransferClient ftp = null;

    try {
        // create client
        log.info("Creating FTP client");
        ftp = new FileTransferClient();

        // set remote host
        log.info("Setting remote host");
        ftp.setRemoteHost(host);
        ftp.setUserName(username);
        ftp.setPassword(password);

        // connect to the server
        log.info("Connecting to server " + host);
        ftp.connect();
        log.info("Connected and logged in to server " + host);

        //Downloading file from server
        log.info("Downloading file");
        ftp.downloadFile(filename+".copy", filename);
        log.info("File downloaded");

        // Shut down client
        log.info("Quitting client");
        ftp.disconnect();

        log.info("Example complete");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error i am receiving is :

`ERROR [FTPClient] 2 Mar 2012 21:44:08.359 : Caught and rethrowing exception in initGet() : Invalid data set name "ABC.DEF.GHI.JKL(0)".  Use MVS Dsname conventions.
com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException: 501 Invalid data set name "ABC.DEF.GHI.JKL(0)".  Use MVS Dsname conventions.
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.validateReply(FTPControlSocket.java:1223)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.initGet(FTPClient.java:3109)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getData(FTPClient.java:3156)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.getFile(FTPClient.java:2970)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.get(FTPClient.java:2356)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.downloadFile(FileTransferClient.java:703)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.downloadFile(FileTransferClient.java:683)
    at com.bluecrossma.ConnectToServer.main(ConnectToServer.java:47)`

Please suggest me on how to resolve this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Found the answer in this link: http://www.torsas.ca/attachments/File/03012008/FTP_Fileref.pdf  Just needed to add single quotes inside the double quotes..Thanks guys.

Comment: interesting setting with single quotes, wow :)

Comment: @javanoob - you should post your comment as an answer, just in case someone has a similar issue in the future and stumbles across this post. Congrats on resolving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer in this link: [torsas.ca/attachments/File/03012008/FTP_Fileref.pdf](http://torsas.ca/attachments/File/03012008/FTP_Fileref.pdf) Just needed to add single quotes inside the double quotes..Thanks guys.

Comment: FTP assumes that dataset names not surounded by quotes are "personal" datasets so your userid is automatically appended to the beginning of the name. Quoting the dataset name tells FTP to use the dataset name as-is.